# Starting nodes on remote machine with different ROS version

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have some launch files that I can start on my control pc that run some nodes on the robot, which is a different pc.
The robot I am working with recently gut updated to ros fuerte, while my control pc still uses ros electric. (If I was in charge I would upgrade the control pc, too, but this is not my decision, I will talk to the responsible people)
Now the problem is, the launch files do not work cross-version.
This is the output I get:

```
remote[i60sr1-0] starting roslaunch
remote[i60sr1-0]: creating ssh connection to i60sr1:22, user[bublitz]
remote[i60sr1-0]: ssh connection created
remote[i60sr1-0]: env: /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roslaunch: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

[i60sr1-0] process has died
remote roslaunch failed to launch: sr1
```

It looks like roslaunch is trying to start another instance of roslaunch on the remote machine, gut is looking for roslaunch in the wrong place.

Now the question is: Is it possible to run nodes remote on a different version of ros? If yes what should I do? I already tried setting the ROS_ROOT variable in a script that is called by env-loader, but that dosn't do it.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39763/starting-nodes-on-remote-machine-with-different-ros-version/) by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 357 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the documentation for the [machine tag](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine). You can set `ros-root` and `ros-package-path` for each machine.

Using two different ROS versions might cause all different kinds of problems and should be avoided though.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-26**:
Yes. The short answer is: "don't mix ROS distros at runtime, it hurts".